# CSS Background Color Position Off

Tags: html, css

I set a background color for a div, but for some reason the color box is not underneath the text, but like 100px toward the top. This is my HTML code;

```
<div class="youtube_gallery_caption">The Fast Show - Unlucky Alf</div>
```

and This is CSS

```
.youtube_gallery_caption  {
background:red;
color:black !important;
width:140px;
height:10px;
padding:10px;
position:relative;
z-index:99;
display:none;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your text is probably higher then `10px`?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.. what is `display:none` in there for..?

Comment: I'm using jQuery for a tooltip effect. You can see it if you go to http://storyville.jonmarkoff.com/storyvillewp/ and hover over any of the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove height and add `line-height:30px`...change the value to whatever height you want. Also, add `overflow: hidden;`. You might also want to add padding to just the left and right, versus all around, so you're not adding to the line-height. Instead this will remove any padding on the top and bottom `padding:0 10px;`

Try replacing your CSS with this:

```
.youtube_gallery_caption  {
    background:red;
    color:black !important;
    width:140px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:0 10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Just removing height did it without adding line-height. Thanks!

Comment: because of the `overflow:hidden;` prob ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your box has a height of 10px, and you font-size isn't specified so is likely larger.

Match up the font-size and line-height with the actual height of the div.

Eg: (using the 10px value):

http://jsfiddle.net/D2g9H/

```
.youtube_gallery_caption {
    background:red;
    color: black !important;
    width:140px;
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
}
```